# Add custom data in Response() of django rest framework while GET?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, response

I am using `Django rest framework`, I have to add my custom data in the `Response()` object.

```
rsp = Response()
rsp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % os.path.basename(file)
rsp['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/export/%s' % file
```

I want to add custome `dict` in the data part of this `Response()`

Hence I tried this,

```
data = {'length': 10}
rsp = Response(data)
```

and

```
data = {'length': 10}
rsp = Response()
rsp['data'] = data
```

But I was getting error as `'error:{'data'}'`

Help me to understand why this behaviour occurred and How to add custom data in `Response()`

Answer (score 1):

When you set `rsp['data']`, it is trying to set a header. This gives an error since data is a dictionary, not a string.

Instead, you should pass the response data as the first argument when you initialise the response:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

data = {'length': 10}
rsp = Response(data)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Alasdair,  I tried this approach also,  but when I am doing `hasattr(response, 'data')` that its returning `False` and also my data is not retirevable

Comment: If I do `rsp = Response(data)`, then `hasattr(rsp, 'data')` returns `True` and `rsp.data` gives the dict.

Comment: Can you tell me, what is possible mistake I am making that return this behaviour to me @Alasdair

Comment: It's difficult to help anymore unless you can give an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: yeah that's fine, Is there are any scenario or implementation that forces this kind of behaviour  or else you have faced this before?

Comment: As I said, it's difficult to help anymore unless you can give an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Alasdair  have you checked, is data field present in response on client side. On server side its present

Comment: @Sanket I checked the code in the shell, not in the client.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for response,  I also getting data field at sever side backend, But its not present at the client side response

Comment: @Sanket have you also faced this issue

Comment: If your problem is in the response by the client, then you need to show a complete example that can reproduce the issue. The two/three line snippets you have shown are not enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'length': 10}
return Response({'data': data})
```

so;

```
response = {}
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % os.path.basename(file)
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/export/%s' % file
return Response(response)
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on the answer?

Comment: yeah, even I also not able to understand

Comment: @origamic can you explore more about your solution